# Optimised way to generate summary of a video?

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, frames

The code which I have written is able to create the summary of the video by skippig the frames with no motion. But it is taking more than 10 times the duration of the video to save the output video. So anyone can please help me with making some changes in the code. It is not the issue with system configuration. I have tried it even in a i7 GPU system.

```
import cv2
import imutils

vs = cv2.VideoCapture("example_01.mp4")
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
pathOut = "output.mp4"



frame_array = []

while True:
    ret,frame = vs.read()
    forig = frame.copy()
    height,width,layers = frame.shape
    size = (width,height)

    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mask = fgbg.apply(gray)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), 
cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)



    for c in cnts:
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)


    if area > 2000:
        frame_array.append(frame)



    out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG'), 20, 
size)
    for i in range(len(frame_array)):
        out.write(frame_array[i])

    out.release()


    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(25)

    if key == ord("q"):
        break
vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: if you want to save it then I wouldn't waste time to display it.

Comment: you should create `out` only once - before `while True`. And write only new frame in file - not all frames again and again in very loop.

Answer (score 2):

I took 18seconds movie and your code on my old computer worked many minutes and it was slowing down so finally I killed it and didn't get output movie.

This code needs ~57 seconds to do the same. If I don't display windows then it needs 39 seconds.

I open `out` only once. I don't append `frame` to `frame_array` but write this one frame directly to file.

```
import cv2
import imutils
import time

vs = cv2.VideoCapture("Wideo/1-sierpinski-carpet-turtle.mp4")
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
pathOut = "output.mp4"

out = None

start = time.time()

while True:
    ret, frame = vs.read()

    if frame is None:
        break

    forig = frame.copy()
    height, width, layers = frame.shape
    size = (width, height)

    if not out:
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG'), 20, size)

    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mask = fgbg.apply(gray)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)

    for c in cnts:
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if area > 2000:
           out.write(frame)
           break # don't check other areas

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(25)

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

end = time.time()
print("time:", end-start)

out.release()
vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Your code opens file again and again and write all frames again and again - so it was slowing down on my computer. You could eventually write it only once after loop.

```
import cv2
import imutils
import time

vs = cv2.VideoCapture("Wideo/1-sierpinski-carpet-turtle.mp4")
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
pathOut = "output.mp4"

frame_array = []

start = time.time()

while True:
    ret, frame = vs.read()

    if frame is None:
        break

    forig = frame.copy()
    height, width, layers = frame.shape
    size = (width, height)

    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mask = fgbg.apply(gray)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)

    for c in cnts:
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if area > 2000:
            frame_array.append(frame)
            break

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(25)

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# --- after loop ---

out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG'), 20, size)
for frame in frame_array:
   out.write(frame)
out.release()

end = time.time()
print("time:", end-start)

vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank You so much furas. It is now working exactly like I wanted . Thank you so much for your effort and time.